# "Swim lane" or "swimlane"?

Tags: spelling

Most books use the term "swim lane", but some articles use the term "swimlane" (for example, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-swimlanes-to-a-flowchart-D794B112-8AA3-4360-8F12-E38BC62AD558). Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such noun + noun collocations are very common in Germanic languages, and English is a Germanic language.

When the collocation becomes used "often enough" — and who is going to be the judge of that but the individual speaker? — you will start to see the nouns presented as a single "word" on the printed or written page, or perhaps with a hyphen separating the nouns, **swim-lane**.

Anyone who tells you that **swimlane** is wrong, or that **swim lane** is wrong, or that **swim-lane** is wrong, or that one or the other of them is "*the* right way", is wrong.

Any literate native speaker will understand that those three different ways of referring to the thing all refer to the same thing.